# C program hangs after fork

Tags: c, fork

I have made the following program : 
The aim is to make 5 child processes and have parent process send a string to each child process
to print. If I pass the argument `xyz` then this program prints `xyz` 2 times and then hangs.
Not sure why that is happening.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int num_processes = 5;
    int pipefd[num_processes][2];
    pid_t cpid;
    char buf;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++)
    {
        if (pipe(pipefd[i]) == -1)
        {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++)
    {
        cpid = fork();
        if (cpid == -1)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (cpid == 0)
        {                        /* Child reads from pipe */
            close(pipefd[i][1]); /* Close unused write end */

            while (read(pipefd[i][0], &buf, 1) > 0)
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
            close(pipefd[i][0]);
        }
        else
        {                        /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
            close(pipefd[i][0]); /* Close unused read end */
            write(pipefd[i][1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
            close(pipefd[i][1]); /* Reader will see EOF */
            wait(NULL);          /* Wait for child */
        }
    }
    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: The child branch should `break` out of the loop and not cycle back to the `fork()`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. In this same code if I wanted the child send something back to the parent process. what should be done ? So it's like now 5 child processes will send data back to parent process. Do I need additional `file descriptors`